# (Simple?) rearrangements

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given

$$
F_v = 6πηrv 
$$

and

$$
F_b = \frac 43 πr^3\sigma g 
$$

then

$$
\frac{F_b}{F_v} = \frac{2r^2\sigma g}{9 \eta v}
$$

The question I'm trying to answer is

*If $F_v$ is ten times greater than $F_b$ when the drop reaches its terminal speed ($v$ = $v_t$) find an equation that expresses the radius of the drop ($r$) in terms of $\sigma$, $g$, $\eta$ and $v_t$*

(n.b. this question is part of a wider set about a water drop falling vertically through the air, and the forces that act upon it)

The 1st part of the given answer is:

If $\frac{F_v}{F_b}$ = 10, when $v$ = $v_t$

$$
10 = \frac{F_v}{F_b} = \frac{1}{(F_b/F_v)} = \frac{9\eta v_t}{2r^2 \sigma g}
$$

If we multiply both sides by $\frac{r^2}{10}$

$$
r^2 = \frac{9\eta v_t}{20\sigma g}
$$

I don't follow this logic.  I've really got 2 questions:

- when $\frac{1}{(F_b/F_v)}$ is applied, then why doesn't the left-hand side also needs to be inversed (i.e. to become $\frac {1}{10}$)? It appears this doesn't happen, since the lhs is then multiplied by $\frac{r^2}{10}$

Making it much more verbose:

$$
10 = \frac{F_v}{F_b} = \frac{1}{(F_b/F_v)}
$$

$$
\frac{10}{1} = \frac{1}{\frac{\frac{4}{3} \pi r^3 \sigma g}{6 \pi \eta r v}} => 
$$

-> how does this lead to the next line?

- (Using a different approach does work, this seems more logical to me - is there a good reason this isn't the way the answer is laid out?)

$$
F_v = 10F_b
$$
$$
6 \pi \eta r v_t = 10 \frac{4}{3} \pi r^3 \sigma g
$$
$$
\frac{18 \eta v_t}{40 \sigma g} = r^2
$$
$$
\frac{9 \eta v_t}{20 \sigma g} = r^2
$$

Answer (score 0):

> ...is there a good reason this isn't the way the answer is laid out?

Well, no. When you go from the second to the third line, you essentially do the same thing. You've merely taken steps in a slightly different order. It's just as correct.

> ...why doesn't the left-hand side also needs to be inversed[?]

In your calculations you point out that $F_v = 10F_b$, so dividing both sides by $F_b$ gives you $10 = \frac{F_v}{F_b}$, which is equivalent to $\frac{1}{F_b/F_v}$. No inversion of 10.

Comment: Argh! I feel really stupid, but I've edited my question with the line I don't follow

Comment: @ChrisW You're confusing the expressions for Fv and Fb. That's why your "more verbose" calculations don't work.

Comment: Hmm, I think I'm just going to accept it without understanding :/

Comment: @ChrisW I'm sorry, you're not confusing anything. But do you agree that $F_v/F_b$ is the same as $\frac{1}{F_b/F_v}$?

Comment: I think what confused me **all** day was the seemingly (to me at least) random insertion of $\frac{1}{F_b/F_v}$ in the answer - I just don't get why the authors put that in the answer;if I ignore that 1 bit I understand it.

Comment: @ChrisW I agree, there is no need for that, simply insert the expressions for Fv and Fb into the original fraction and the result is the same.